# How to stop turpentine from caching my "header" block, and only use page cache?

Tags: cache, turpentine

In my `header.phtml`, I have a front page-specific HTML (`H1` tag) under `$this->getIsHomePage()` condition. I need this `H1` to appear only on front page.

The problem is: under Turpentine, this `H1` tag appears on every page. I believe it's because Turpentine caches the block for the whole site.

By default, `turpentine_esi.xml` has the following configuration for `header` block:

```
    <!--
    A default Magento site includes a logged in user's name in the welcome
    message and the number of items in the shopping cart so it must be
    cached per-client.
    -->
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <access>private</access>
                <flush_events>
                    <wishlist_item_save_after/>
                    <wishlist_item_delete_after/>
                    <sales_quote_save_after/>
                </flush_events>
            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

I don't have the login info in the header template, so I believe I can just drop the `header` block from the configuration (or rather override it in `local.xml`).

The solution I can think of is: don't cache `header` block in Turpentine at all, cache it in the full page HTML. So I removed this piece from `turpentine_esi.xml`.

**Problem is**: the H1 block is still rendered on all the pages.

I have restarted varnish, php5-fpm, physically deleted Magento's `var/cache`, flushed blocks, ESI blocks and page HTML cache in admin... and I still see the wrong version of header template, with `H1` on every page.

Another way, I tried to change the `header` caching options to `public` - this didn't help either:

```
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <access>public</access>
            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I needed to override (remove) the `header` block from `turpentine_esi.xml` in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml`. My `local.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <action method="setEsiOptions">
            </action>
        </reference>

        <!-- We at Tahta.com.ua only need to cache the cart block. -->
        <reference name="top_cart_block">
            <action method="setEsiOptions">
                <params>
                    <access>private</access>
                    <flush_events>
                        <wishlist_item_save_after/>
                        <wishlist_item_delete_after/>
                        <sales_quote_save_after/>
                    </flush_events>
                </params>
            </action>
        </reference>

    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Good answer but DO NOT change files in base folder because they will be overwritten by the next Magento upgrade. Just add the changes in the local.xml from your theme folder: app/design/frontend/your-theme/default/layout/local.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
<reference name="header">
 <action method="setEsiOptions">
    <params>
        <access>private</access>
    </params>
 </action>
</reference>
```

Also please refer this link https://rajeshganjeer.wordpress.com/2014/05/28/varnish-with-magento-terpentine/

Comment: Didn't help. The documentation (https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/ESI_Cache_Policy) says: `"private: one version per client is stored in cache (the session cookie identifies which client gets which cached version of the block)"`. Isn't this the direct opposite of what I need? I need to cache the block not by client, but by a page: front page keeps one version for every client, other pages keep their own version.